# getting value from JTable to an array

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

Hey I was trying to get the values from a JTable to an array and then print it. I seems like it is actually taking the adress of something instead of taking the value. I don't understand why.
Here is my code:

```
public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount();
    int nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol ; j++)
        tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tableData));
    return tableData;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DefaultTableModel model = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();

```
    model.addColumn("Col1");
    model.addColumn("Col2");

    model.addRow(new Object[]{"1", "v2"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"2", "v2"});

    List<String> numdata = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int count = 0; count < model.getRowCount(); count++){
          numdata.add(model.getValueAt(count, 0).toString());
    }

    System.out.println(numdata);
```

try this

Comment: you can get a clue for your problem

Answer (score 0):

you have to use System.out.println(Array.toString(//your code here));

Comment: otherwise as you've encountered it prints a memory location instead of the visual value

Comment: thanks but i still get the same thing; I get this "[[Ljava.lang.Object;@6f434304]"

Comment: well now that i think of it you have a println and a return method for Public Object try deleting the return method and see what happens (p.s it might help future awnserers if you include a bit of the main where you call public object

Comment: I did it but it does not work, I dont see how deleting the return would do anything since the println is just before it.

Comment: well I'm stumped now to my best guess right now is that your not calling this method correctly in the main try going through the main and checking for tiny logic errors like 1/0 or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

List< Object> list = new ArrayList< Object>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){

```
    for (int j = 0; j < nCol ; j++)
     list.add(dtm.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
```

}

Comment: i get a error as well:  at components.CompleteListeFrame.getTableData(CompleteListeFrame.java:301)