# How to get data from a 2d object array?

Tags: java, arrays

As described in [tuytuys question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032693/getting-value-from-jtable-to-an-array) i get data from a jTable to an 2d array.

```
Object [][] newarr = null;

newarr = getTableData(jTable);
```

the code of getTableData:

```
public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount();
    int nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol ; j++)
        tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(tableData));
    return tableData;
}
```

The newarr 2d object array contains the data of the jTable, I have debugged it.

The question is: How may I get the string data from the 2d object array in which is the string from the cell of the jTable?

```
String s = newarr[0][1].toString();
```

for example is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by *is not working.*

Comment: "is not working". actually, it is, but maybe it doesn't produce the output you want, because it is the Object class's toString method you use, or you get a NPE somewhere

Comment: try to explicitly cast your object with `(String) newarr[0][1]` instead of using `toString()` method from Object class

Comment: Yes you are allright. "Not working" was not exact enough. I need the string which was in the jTable. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is cast `Object` to `String`. To do that just make sure that `newarr[0][1]` is `instanceof String`. Example code using `?` insted of `if` statement. What I did is basically check if `newarr[0][1]` is `String` then assign it to `s` else assign `""`:

```
String s = (newarr[0][1] instanceof String) ? (String)newarr[0][1] : "";
```